# ADB command am start - open settings sub-page

Tags: adb, settings

On a TC52 ZEBRA, I need the ADB command (am start) to change the settings.

With  `am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings` command my settings window opens.

But if I want to have a sub-page access (Keyboard settings for example) what adb command I need to use?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39873312/150978)  is a bit old but it contains a lot of activity names you need to start a specific settings page. Depending on the Android version on your device the names may have changed, so expect some of them to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to trigger tapping with opening settings:

```
adb shell input tap <x> <y>
```

Also, for cursor emulation:

```
adb shell input keyevent <19|20|21|22>
```

For triggering key:

```
adb shell input keyevent 66
adb shell input keyevent TAB
adb shell input keyevent ENTER
```

Then to start settings there's:

```
adb shell am start -a com.android.settings
```

To finish there's:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.settings
```

So, to start:

```
adb shell am start -a <settings choice>

com.android.settings
com.android.settings.APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS
com.android.settings.DISPLAY_SETTINGS
com.android.settings.DOCK_SETTINGS
com.android.settings.QUICK_LAUNCH_SETTINGS
com.android.settings.SOUND_SETTINGS
com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS
com.android.settings.VOICE_INPUT_OUTPUT_SETTINGS
android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS
android.settings.ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS
android.settings.ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS_ADD_ACCOUNT
android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS
android.settings.APN_SETTINGS
android.settings.APPLICATION_SETTINGS
android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS
android.settings.DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS
android.settings.DATE_SETTINGS
android.settings.DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS
android.settings.DISPLAY_SETTINGS
android.settings.INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS
android.settings.INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS
android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS
android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS
android.settings.MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS
android.settings.MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS
android.settings.MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS
android.settings.PRIVACY_SETTINGS
android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS
android.settings.SETTINGS
android.settings.SOUND_SETTINGS
android.settings.SYNC_SETTINGS
android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS
android.settings.USER_DICTIONARY_SETTINGS
android.settings.WIFI_IP_SETTINGS
android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS
android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS
ACCESSIBILITY_FEEDBACK_SETTINGS
android.net.vpn.SETTINGS
android.search.action.SEARCH_SETTINGS
android.search.action.WEB_SEARCH_SETTINGS
```